# Eclipse freezes when erlide tries to run

Tags: erlang, erlide

I'm just getting started with erlide, using a fresh install of Eclipse Juno and erlide.  I've used erlang on my system (64-bit Fedora) from the command-line, so I'm just trying to make the switch.  I started with R15B, and have upgraded to R15B02 (built from source) as suggested by another SO post.  If I right-click on a .erl file and pick Run As..Erlang Application, the IDE freezes and I have to kill it.  If I try to run from Run Configurations and specify the module and function, it will start to execute, but never progresses beyond 27%.  This is on a simple function that runs instantaneously on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the latest nightly from http://erlide.org/update_nightly, we did some work about similar issues, I hope they will solve yours too.

It would help to see the log from /erlide.log.

You can also open the launch configuration from run->configurations and see if there is some weird value in any of the fields in the "runtime" tab, most probably the node host name.

[I will be away for a week or so, so I can't answer very soon. Sorry about that.]

/Vlad